# How do I force label and dropdown to be on same line?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to force the dropdown and the label to be on the same line. How can I force this. Because for now I get the label : `Taste` above the dropdown.

```
export default function MenuItemDisplay() {
    ...
    return (
        <div>
            ...
            <div className="TextData"> 
                Taste : <CustomDropdown style={styles.select} options={TASTE} defaultValue={LIKELIHOOD.find((t) => t.label === item.taste)} />
            </div>
            ...

        </div >
    );
}
```

CustomDropdown:

```
export default function CustomDropdown({ style, options, styleSelect, defaultValue, isMulti }) {
    return <div style={style}>
        <Select styles={styleSelect} options={options} defaultValue={defaultValue} isMulti={isMulti} />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: you don't have a `<label>`, so I assume you mean the unwrapped, entirely non-functional and unhelpful text that precedes the component that becomes a `<select>` element? Since CSS works with HTML (*after* React has finished processing the components, and composed a DOM), could you post the (relevant) "*[mcve]*" HTML that's created?

Comment: you mean same horizontal line. if so you can use display:flex; or display:grid then grid-template-columns:auto auto;

Comment: Here is my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-how-do-i-display-specific-data-from-json-that-fullfill-a-condition-forked-z37eu1?file=/src/MenuItemDisplay.jsx). Yes I want horizontal line. I tried flex, horizontal align, inline-block. But I don't see where I'm wrong

Comment: @Zokulko thats great news. I'll put the answer. and then you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. or display:flex

```css
.textData {
    display:grid; 
    grid-template-columns:auto auto; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing that I would do is wrap your 'label' in paragraph tags, because from a semantics point of view text should not be wrapped solely in a div.

```
<div className="TextData"> 
  <p>Taste :</p>

  <CustomDropdown 
    style={styles.select} 
    options={TASTE} 
    defaultValue={LIKELIHOOD.find((t) => t.label === item.taste)} 
  />
</div>
```

Secondly, in order to get everything on the same line, you can add 'display: flex' to the the TextData class. By default, content within a flexbox is on the same line.

If you then wish to center your content horizontally and vertically, you can add 'align-items: center' and 'justify-content: center' to the same div.

Comment: Why is it semantically a `<p>` element, as opposed to a `<label>` (for example)?

Comment: Labels should be bound to an element, ordinarily by using the 'for' attribute. This requires the target to have an id, which the OP's Select elements don't appear to have.  Binding may also be achieved by putting the element between the label tags. Nonetheless, conventionally, the use of labels is restricted to certain components (OP's Select component is a custom React component, as opposed to a vanilla HTML 'select' element). So yes, a label could be used, but for simplicity's sake and given the available code, I recommended a paragraph tag instead.